# Error Java, Unhandled event loop exception No more handles

Tags: java, eclipse

¿Alguien me podría decir a qué se debe este error? Me pasó cuando quise empezar a utilizar Eclipse, debido a que normalmente utilizo NetBeans.

El error es:

> Unhandled event loop exception
>
> No more handles

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: Errores en capturas]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En un problema similar al tuyo, planteado en [SO en Inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15594590/5587982), se encontró una solución de la siguiente manera:

Cambiar el editor de Java para WindowBuilder. Para ello tienes que ir a:
`Eclipse/Windows/Preferences` y una vez en `Preferences` ir a: `General/Editors/File Associations` y allí elegir **`WindowBuilder Java Editor`** como editor predeterminado.

---

- Si tienes problemas con el Window Builder, puedes descargarlo [aquí](http://archive.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/release/R201309271200/4.3/).
- Señalar también que en 2013 [fue reportado un bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=402983) con este mensaje en Eclipse, el cual no tiene el status *Resuelto*, sino que tiene el estatus: `CLOSED NOT_ECLIPSE`, lo cual significa que este error se puede reproducir debido a componentes externos de Eclipse tales como plugins o complementos que intentes usar y que no estén disponibles o que estén desactualizados.

Si la solución planteada más arriba no resuelve tu problema podrías intentar otras de las planteadas en las respuestas y comentarios de este mismo problema planteado en SO en Inglés (enlace más arriba).

### Otra posible causa: Team Viewer

La respuesta más votada en SO en Inglés, aunque no aparece marcada como solución , indica que el problema podría estar ligado a Team Viewer.

Quienes hayan experimentado este problema después de haber instalado Team Viewer, es muy probable que puedan resolver el problema siguiendo los pasos indicados en esa respuesta en específico.

Answer (score 1):

A mí me pasaba lo mismo y fue desde que instalé Zoom, la aplicación de videollamadas de moda. Tengo [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) [debian](/questions/tagged/debian). Leyendo esto https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=545425 encontré que Zoom, requiere un paquete llamado iBUS, que hace que Eclipse saque logs por la ventana. La solución que encontré fue ésta https://stackoverflow.com/a/58934989/4067559 que simplemente es añadir esta línea al archivo `~/.profile`

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
```